# How can the boundary of a Riemannian $3$-manifold consist of minimal surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity, minimal-surfaces

I'm studying a research paper, and there is a theorem whose statement looks very strange to me. In 2001, Gerhard Huisken and Tom Ilmanen proposed a theorem in their collaborative work *THE INVERSE MEAN CURVATURE FLOW AND THE RIEMANNIAN PENROSE INEQUALITY*:

> **Main Theorem** (Riemannian Penrose Inequality)**.** *Let $M$ be a complete, connected $3$-manifold. Suppose that:*
>
> (i) *$M$ has nonnegative scalar curvature.*
>
> (ii) *$M$ is asymptotically flat satisfying (0.1) and (0.2), with ADM mass $m$.*
>
> (iii) *The boundary of $M$ is compact and consists of minimal surfaces, and $M$ contains no other compact minimal surfaces.*
>
> *Then*
> $$m\geq\sqrt{\frac{|N|}{16\pi}},$$
> *where $|N|$ is the area of any connected component of $\partial M$. Equality holds if and only if $M$ is isometric to one-half of the spatial Schwarzschild manifold.*

Please allow me to omit the conditions (0.1) and (0.2) because they are imposed solely on the Riemannian metric on $M$ and its Ricci curvature.

As indicated by the title, my question lies in the assumption (iii). I know $\partial M$ is a surface in $M$ and therefore qualifies as a candidate for minimal surfaces in $M$, but is it really possible for $\partial M$ to consist of minimal surfaces in $M$? If I take a minimal surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as an example, is it really possible to break $S$ into pieces with each piece being a minimal surface in its own right?

Thank you.

**Edit.** I know minimal surfaces can be defined in several equivalent ways, but please allow me to adopt the familiar mean-curvature definition, in which a minimal surface is characterized by requiring that its mean curvature vanish at each point. Now, can we join together a family of minimal surfaces smoothly to get another minimal surface? The authors seem to indicate that $\partial M$ is this another minimal surface. Thank you.

Comment: Its not clear what's your doubt. You seem to know that it is possible that $\partial M$ is a minimal surface anyway. Or put it another way, why do you think it is impossible?

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you. I was wondering what the authors meant by saying that $\partial M$ consists of minimal surfaces. Does that mean $\partial M$ is the union of a family of minimal surfaces? Also, why did the authors assume that $M$ contains no other compact minimal surfaces? It sounds like $M$ does contain a compact minimal surface. If so, what is it really?

Comment: @ArcticChar Now I am told that there exists no compact minimal surface, a result that can be found in elementary differential geometry.

Comment: Well, who told you that? Isn't any horizontal slice $S^2 \times \{t\}$ a compact minimal surface in $S^2 \times \mathbb R$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Sorry, it's my bad. That assertion applies in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which can be found in books such as do Carmo and Pressley. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544134/there-are-no-compact-minimal-surfaces